# Missing equal sign on simple update statement using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm using **apex oracle** and running into **missing equal sign** error on this simple update statement. Can someone please point out what's wrong with this query?

> `update product_t
> set qty-onhand = 11000
> where productid = 28`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qty-onhand` is `column qty` ***minus*** `column onhand`.

You need to 'escape' the column name *(or just use a better column name, without a minus sign in it)*.

```
update product_t
set "qty-onhand" = 11000
where productid = 28
```

Comment: I wonder this is a bug or not practically shouldnt have happened either way you may be correct

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja - No, it's not a bug, not in the DBMS or parser at least.  If you don't quote/escape that column name, then it's not a column name, it's an arithmetic expression; `qty-onhand` is parsed in exactly the same way as `qty - onhand` would be.  If you had `SET x = y-z` would you expect to get `y minus z` or `the column "y-z"`??  That's why column names should typically be alphanumeric and `_` only, anything else leads to problems and mistakes.

Comment: Just tried your solution @MatBailie and the update query seems to work with all other columns. Could you please elaborate on escaping the column name please?

Comment: @Noobie - I showed you in the answer, by putting quotes around the column name *(My answer has `SET "qty-onhand" = ` in place of your `SET qty-onhand =`)*; to tell the parser that it's not an arithmetic expression, it's a column name with a hyphen in it.

Comment: @MatBailie - Thanks so much for the explanation. It makes perfect sense. I had to also match the case sensitivity while putting the column name in quotes. It works now!